# Without using truth tables show that $p \to (p \vee q)$ is a tautology.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Without using truth tables show that $p \to (p \vee q)$ is a tautology.  Hint $a \to b \equiv \neg a \vee b$.

Comment: Have you tried using the hint?  Do you understand it?  Can you write the result of applying it?

Comment: result of applying it?

Comment: Did you show that the proof system was sound in the first place?

Comment: Which rules are you allowed to use? If you use natural deduction the derivation is easy, you can assume (p) and then derivate (p ∨ q) by using the rule of introduction of the disjunction (which is what actually this formula represents).

Comment: Why do not apply the hint ?

Answer (score 5):

$$
p\to (p\vee q)\equiv (\neg p)\vee (p\vee q) \equiv (\neg p \vee p)\vee q \equiv \top\vee q \equiv \top
$$

Answer (score 0):

That was a weird hint!

My hint: Try a proof by contradiction using the equivalence: $A\lor B~~\equiv~~ \neg(\neg A \land \neg B)$.

---

EDIT

Another hint: Here are my suggested first two lines:

1. $p~~~~$(Assume)
2. $\neg (p\lor q)~~~~$(Assume)

Comment: I am not sure I follow